# PageReference.getURL() returning URL:[delegate:{MY RELATIVE URL}]

Tags: apex, unit-test, url, pagereference

Im am trying to get the URL of one of my PageReferences whenever i call its method to return it to me i get this result **URL:[delegate:{MY RELATIVE URL}]**. Anyone know if why it's returning this, **Please** no hacks trying to parse this string. I will note that the redirect bit is set to true in case that has anything to do with it. I am looking for an explanation, or perhaps something that I'm missing or doing wrong.

```
/* Cancel and Return to previous screen */
public PageReference cancel(){
   this.retUrl = retUrl.setRedirect(true);
   return this.retUrl;
}
```

.... Test Class

```
PageReference prCancel = controller.cancel();
//Test the redirects
Test.setCurrentPage( new PageReference(Url.getSalesforceBaseURL() + prCancel.getURL()) );
string currentPageURLString = Url.getSalesforceBaseURL() + ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();
string lookingForURL = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/'+controller.opportunityClone.Id+'/';
```

== LOG OUPUT ==

10:09:10:739 USER_DEBUG [204]|DEBUG|Url:[delegate=https://cs30.salesforce.com]/006n00000082U10AAE/

Comment: Might be easier to understand the issue if you could post a code snippet and example of the return value.

Comment: Suggest you post the minimal code that demonstrates the problem; not something I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test.setCurrentPage( new PageReference(Url.getSalesforceBaseURL() + prCancel.getURL()) );`

is wrong.

`Test.setCurrentPage( new PageReference(prCancel.getURL()) );`

getSalesforceBaseUrl returns a URL object. The delegate bit is what is being pumped up out by URL.toString().

```
PageReference prCancel = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account()).cancel(); //Test the redirects
    Test.setCurrentPage( new PageReference(prCancel.getURL()) );
    string currentPageURLString = Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() + ApexPages.currentPage().getURL()();
    string lookingForURL = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/xxx/';
    System.assert(false, currentPageURLString);
```

Returns: https://*.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp in my test